# JQUERY : CSS does not apply to dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am creating an ajax call with success function as below

```
for (i = 1; i < selector_names.length; i++) {
    if (selector_names[i] == "placement") {
        add_options = "";
        for (j = 0; j < option_names[i].length; j++) {
            add_options += "<div class='option-container'><input class='check-box-" + selector_names[i] + "' type='checkbox' id='" + option_names[i][j] + "' checked='checked'/><label class='option-label' for='" + option_names[i][j] + "'>" + option_names[i][j] + "</label></div>";
        }
    }
}
$("#Placement").next().append(add_options);
```

These are the styles i applied to the div, checkboxes and lables:

```
.option-container {
    padding:1% 1% 1% 0%;
}
input {
    postion:relative;
    vertical-align:middle;
    height:12px;
    width:12px;
    border-radius: 50px;
}
.option-label {
    margin:2%;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#000;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

However, the styles are different for dynamically added elements compared to those I manually created. Why is this happeing ?

Here is how it looks like, the first 2 checkboxes are manually created and the next two are dynamically generated. The #Placement div I am appending to is hidden by default and expands when clicked on the title.

[image]

The difference is small but noticeable.

When I modify the CSS, it applies for both type of elements by the difference between the default and jquery created ones still remain. For example if i increase the margin on the .option-container, it increases for both, but the relative difference still remain.

HTML of the manually created checkboxes:

```
<div class="option-container">
<input class="check-box-placement" type="checkbox" id="pdpv1" checked="checked"/>
<label class="option-label" for="pdpv1">pdpv1</label>
</div>
<div class="option-container"> 
<input class="check-box-placement" type="checkbox" id="pdph1" checked="checked"/>
<label class="option-label" for="pdph1">pdph1</label>
</div>
```

Comment: can you post the HTML code of those 2 manually created checkboxes

Comment: a Demo would help as well

Comment: Fix the invalid markup (remove the closing `</span>` tags) and try again

Comment: @Andreas I think that the seemingly invalid markup is there because it assumes that two span tags are opened before it reaches there. It might be a "good practices, please" candidate.

Comment: removing the <span> did not make any difference. These new elements are created on page load, should that be a concern ?

Comment: @Frederik.L If so, the closing tags have to be placed before the `div.option-container` and not right after it... - Nevertheless the markup is invalid in either case

Comment: removing the span tags did not work, any more suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jQuery is tagged in the OP, I'd suggest to use a little bit more of jQuery's semantic, rather than looking for some string issues.

One way is to use jQuery's `clone()` method to reproduce the same markup, instead of dealing with a string. Crafted html strings are impossible to read. As I don't have any example values of `selector_names` and `option_names`, I assumed default values in the demo and simplified a bit. It can go like this:

```
var $optionContainerModel = $('.option-container:first');
var $placementNext = $('#Placement').next();
for (var i = 0; i < selector_names.length; i++) {
    if (selector_names[i] == "placement") {
        var $newoption = $optionContainerModel.clone();
        $newoption.find('.check-box-placement').attr('id', 'cbp'+i);
        var $label = $newoption.find('.option-label');
        $label.attr('for', 'cbp'+i);
        $label.text( option_names[i] );
        $placementNext.append( $newoption );
    }
}
```

The main caveat happens whenever you don't have at least one container to clone. But if the goal of the ajax success is to copy a checkbox template, then it may be more readable to actually make a copy out of it.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/g4qcw8Lw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

in your HTML string:

```
"<div class='option-container'></span></span><input class='check-box-"+selector_names[i]+"' type='checkbox' id='"+option_names[i][j]+"' checked='checked'/><label class='option-label' for='"+option_names[i][j]+"'>"+option_names[i][j]+"</label></div>"
```

you open a DIV, close 2 span tags, add self-closing checkbox and label before closing the first DIV. Turn the first span tag into an openning tag or remove both span tags from the HTML string to repair.

If there are earlier openned span tags which make this markup valid.. remove them unless your inserting all the HTML in one go, the HTML engine will probably auto-close the previously added openning span tags, or just mess up all HTML rendering from that point onwards. You shouldn't add HTML tags piecemeal or else the browser won't match openning and closing tags reliably.

I'd recommend you use a template-ing JavaScript library (knockout/handlebars etc..) to construct HTML like this so you don't have to search for bugs in strings.

Comment: I removed the </span> tags completely but it does not make a difference. The DOM structures looks perfect. Any more suggestions ?

Comment: hmm, switch from % in your CSS to px based sizing. In dev tools, which elements have the wrong sizing, it looks like one element is missing a top margin and the label is missing a left margin.